# Is Kylo Ren a prince?

Tags: star-wars, kylo-ren, princess-leia

Princess Leia remained a princess after the destruction of Alderaan.  In the new novel *Bloodline*, another member of the galactic royal houses says that Leia is entitled to a planetary governorship, which Ben would eventually inherit.

> Princess Leia smiled at the kind mention of her parents. “My point is, I shouldn’t be the person inheriting the governorship of Birren in the first place.”
>
> “But of course you should! None of the Elder Houses adjudicates succession through strict bloodline inheritance.” Privately Lady Carise held some reservations about this. Bloodlines had to matter somewhat, otherwise the very concept of royalty would be discounted. However, she believed that inner nobility could be demonstrated through action, and despite her political disagreements with the princess, Lady Carise felt nobody could deny Leia’s courage was the equal of any monarch’s. **“You must succeed Lord Mellowyn, just as your son must someday succeed you.”**
>
> For a moment Princess Leia looked weary, as if she had aged between one sentence and the next. “I can’t see Ben taking much interest in the governorship, either. Really, it would be better for everyone concerned if I were to remove myself from the succession. Wouldn’t it then fall to you? Birren was settled by both Alderaanian and Arkanisian explorers, after all.”
>   -  *Star Wars:  Bloodline*

There is no indication in *The Force Awakens* that Kylo ever considered himself a prince, but is he a prince anyway?

Comment: If he was a prince, he'd be the prince of a long dead planet. So it's pretty much an empty title. Just thought I'd point that out

Comment: Does the quote from *Bloodlines* not answer this question?

Comment: @adamant - No, because technically they were talking about a governorship that Leia's family was entitled to, not the actual monarchical title.

Comment: Prince Ren has a nice ring to it, like Lord Vader or Count Dooku.

Comment: @Arden - but the nobility was still devoted to their status as the Elder Houses,  and respected Leia's position as princess immensely.

Comment: he was a half-blood prince. His father was a scoundrel. Only his mother was royal ;)

Comment: @NKCampbell - actually, his father was a royal. Ref: C3PO in "*Courtship of Princess Leia*". My deepest apologies to everyone for reminding that that novel existed.

Comment: Is there any deeper meaning then to the quote in beginning of TFA, "The General?  I knew her as royalty!". Did she maybe renounce her royal titles as she suggests in the quote you linked? What was Carise's response to Leia's question in the last sentence?

Answer (score 12):

## Probably not in a formal sense

This is a difficult question to answer without formal statements on the matter — and there are none.  Still, there is room for reasonable speculation.

Planetary governorship aside, Leia was a princess on Alderaan, a planet that unfortunately no longer exists due to the intervention of the Empire.

While Leia herself retains her royal titles, it seems to me that new members of the family, namely Ben Solo, might not be *formally invested* with the title of Prince, given that the site of investiture no longer exists.

Instead, it is more likely that Ben Solo is simply an *heir apparent*, and would be invested with the appropriate title should some "New Alderaan" be settled with monarchial ties to the old one.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that these titles are based on public opinion. Leia might be considered a Princess on a New Alderaan because she's earned it, but Ben has in fact done the opposite.